# Pigpio control of SG90 servo is imprecise on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, servo

I'm in the process of trying to build a laser turret using two SG90 servos, a laser diode and my Raspberry Pi.

I've come to realize that the pigpio library I'm using to control the servo seems a bit imprecise, so I've written a short test program:

```
import pigpio
import time

pi = pigpio.pi()

def do():
    pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(17, 1500)
    for pulsewidth in range(1600, 1650):
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(17, pulsewidth)
        print("pulsewidth: " + str(pulsewidth))
        time.sleep(0.1)

do()
```

When running the code, I saw that not every new pulsewidth actually changes the position of the servo, the servo rather jumps to a new position every ~5-10 or so steps. Since I'm aiming the laser at a wall 3m away, those jumps are really obvious and it makes it hard, if not impossible, to correctly aim at something.

Is this a problem I can solve by using another library or method or something or is that simply the limit of the SG90 servos?

Also, if there is a better forum to ask this, feel free to give me pointers.

Comment: I don't have a datasheet for the SG90, but I doubt it has a resolution much better  (ie. smaller) than 1° without gearing. Also see [Micro/standard servo resolution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234788/micro-standard-servo-resolution).

Comment: You'll need to determine if the skips are in the PWM signal or in the servo.  Observe the signal on an oscilloscope to see if it jumps when the servo jumps.  If so, the signal is bad.  If not, then it's the servo.

Comment: Also, compare your results to [piServoCtl.](https://pypi.org/project/piServoCtl/)  Your code looks kind odd to me, but it has been several years since I did any servo controls on  a Pi.

Comment: @JRE I don't have an oscilloscope sadly. Earliest I might have access to one is when our university reopens. I will try that other library though, thank you!

Comment: @ocrdu I will take a look at that, thank you too!

Comment: @JRE piServoCtl works way better, thank you!